# I want to make table with no columns only rows with data

Tags: tables

I want to make a table in which data is added in rows but no columns like this

[image]

you can see in this pic all the data is in rows no columns.how can i make it in latex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your table has one column, isn't it? :-). Is table width equal to text width? What you tray so far, your table is very elementary ...

Comment: i want to make table like that in latex

Comment: u can see pic @Zarko

Comment: Of course I see your picture, but I like to see, what you try so far. This site doesn't provide service " we do your task (for free of charge)"  ...

Answer (score 6):

- You should make yourself more familiar with LaTeX!
- Your table is very elementary, so if would look around for some introductory text, you would found an example of table
- I'm not willing to rewrite your table content, this you will do yourself ;-)

As starting point can serve the following MWE (Minimal Working Example)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|}
    \hline
\textbf{text: text}         \\
    \hline
\textbf{text:} more text    \\
    \hline
\textbf{text:}\newline
more text                   \\
    \hline
\textbf{text:} more text    \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

which after compilation produce the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I gather that it's important to you that all cells have equal height. If you need to let this table break across pages, I suggest you employ a `longtable` environment, with a single column of type `p` (short for "paragraph"). In the following example, instances of `\\` ("double backslash") are inserted where needed to give all cells equal height.

[image]

I think, though, that a `decription` environment would be better suited than either a `longtable` or a `tabularx` environment for the task at hand. You'd have to give up on all those vertical and horizontal rules; however, that would likely be a good thing anyway, when viewed from a design and layout perspective.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array}
\begin{document}

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{longtable}{| p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax} |}
\hline
\textbf{Test Case ID: T4} \\ 
\\ % blank row
\hline
\textbf{Test Case:} Validation of order and money deduction \\
\\ % blank row
\hline
\dots \\
\\ % blank row
\hline
\textbf{Flow:} After successful placement of order check balance in a wallet that is deducted according to the order or not.\\
\hline
\dots \\
\\ % blank row
\hline
\end{longtable}


\bigskip
\hrule
\begin{description}
\item[Test Case ID] T4
\item[Test Case] Validation of order and money deduction
\item[\dots] \dots
\item[Flow] After successful placement of order check balance  
  in a wallet that is deducted according to the order or not
\item[\dots] \dots \
\end{description}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've recently started learning to use Jupyter Notebooks and had to develop Markdown Tables in some notebooks, which isn't particularly complex but it is quite finicky. I was turned on to [TablesGenerator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/) as a useful GUI to easily create a table, which then pumps out the necessary text to be copy/pasted into your desired destination. [TablesGenerator also works with LaTeX](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables) and is very easy to use. Pasting in the data you provided, I get the following code to generate a LaTeX table:

```
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
% \useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
Test Case ID: T4                                                                                                      \\ \hline
Test Case: Validation of order and money deduction                                                                    \\ \hline
Tester: Ahad Nadeem                                                                                                   \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Precondition:\\ Successful placement of order.\end{tabular}                                \\ \hline
Flow: After successful placement of order check balance in a wallet that it is deducted according to the order or not \\ \hline
Postcondition: The deduction was wrong after order placement                                                          \\ \hline
Test Case Status: try again                                                                                           \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Note that this doesn't include the boldface that you were using, as Tables Generator can only indicate if you want all or none of a cell to be bold, rather than only parts of a cell. If you want to use boldface titling for your data, I'd probably redo the table slightly to have 2 columns, the first being a label/title (Test Case, Tester, etc.) and the second being your actual data (Validation of..., Ahad Nadeem, etc.)

I've not used it for LaTeX myself, but it works extremely well for Markdown Tables and for something as simple as your table here (which does, by the way, have 1 column, not 0 columns), it should be pretty easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

Example of a table with a fixed length value:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ | p{15mm} |}
\hline
text \\ \hline
text \\ \hline
text \\ \hline
text \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ | p{100pt} |}
\hline
text \\ \hline
text \\ \hline
text \\ \hline
text \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ | p{10cm} |}
\hline
text \\ \hline
text \\ \hline
text \\ \hline
text \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```